# XML-22103: (Fatal Error) DOMResult can not be this kind of node

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have got an error during the request to an Web-service.

I used Spring boot 3.x

```xml
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>apps</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>2.1</target>
                                               <episodeFileName>episode_apps</episodeFileName>
                            <xjbSources>
                                <xjbSource>src/main/resources/appstms.xjb</xjbSource>
                            </xjbSources>

                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/resources/xsd/schema-apps.xsd</source>
                            </sources>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
<!--
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.parent.relativePath}/src/main/java/by/*/reception/electronic/docs/service/
                            </outputDirectory>-->
                            <packageName>*.reception.electronic.docs.service.generated.xml.entrypoint</packageName>

                        <!--    <outputDirectory>*.reception.electronic.docs.service.generate
                            </outputDirectory>-->

                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

- config

```java
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://*.com/apps";


    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    @Bean(name = "apsMessage")
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext appContext){

        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();

        servlet.setApplicationContext(appContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {

        SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
        messageFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_12);
        return messageFactory;
    }



    /* localhost:8080/ws/appsTms.wsdl
     * */
    @Bean(name = "appsTms")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(@Qualifier("appsTmsSchema") XsdSchema schema){

        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();

        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ApsPort");

        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");

        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace(NAMESPACE_URI);

        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(schema);

        wsdl11Definition.setCreateSoap11Binding(true);
        wsdl11Definition.setCreateSoap12Binding(true);

        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean(name = "appsTmsSchema")
    public XsdSchema moviesSchema(){

        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/schema-apps.xsd"));

    }
}
```

- And an endpoint

```java
@Endpoint
public class MessageEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( MessageEndpoint.class );

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://*.com";


    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "Multiply")
    @ResponsePayload
    public MultiplyResponse getMultiplyResponse(@RequestPayload Multiply messageRequest) throws Exception {

        String fileName1 = messageRequest.getFileName1();

        System.out.println(fileName1);

        MultiplyResponse response = new MultiplyResponse();
        response.setReturn("");

        return response;
    }
}
```

When I try to execute a query and pass Xml, I don't even get to the class where the web service endpoint is located.

I have an error :

> 08-06-2020 16:44:27.935  INFO 14660
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet
>   'dispatcherServlet'
>
> XML-22103: (Fatal Error) DOMResult can not be this kind of node. 
>   08-06-2020 16:44:27.936 DEBUG 14660
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected
>   StandardServletMultipartResolver  08-06-2020 16:44:27.951 DEBUG 14660 
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers
>   will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
>   08-06-2020 16:44:27.951  INFO 14660
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in
>   15 ms  08-06-2020 16:44:27.952 DEBUG 14660
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST
>   "/error", parameters={}  08-06-2020 16:44:27.955 DEBUG 14660
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
>   08-06-2020 16:44:27.976 DEBUG 14660
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json',
>   given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json,
>   application/json, application/*+json]  08-06-2020 16:44:27.976 DEBUG
>   14660   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing
>   [{timestamp=Mon Jun 08 16:44:27 MSK 2020, status=500, error=Internal
>   Server Error, message=, path=/ws (truncated)...]  08-06-2020
>   16:44:28.004 DEBUG 14660   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500

Any idea what it is and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is follow:

The **adjoining system** work by own xsd and to have a namespace uri that is mapped with documents that is send to web service.

The **adjoining system** is an mediator and recieve xml documents for sending to another system for processing.

First off she look up  into  and than she suppose, that an endpoint in a web-service (soap) имеет specific namespace, that is pointed into xsd , on based was built WSDL.

The adjiong system able to work with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://ws.transit.ls.com"
           targetNamespace="http://ws.transit.ls.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="Multiply">
....
```

- **Note** :   targetNamespace="http://ws.transit.ls.com"

You must point such **targetNamespace** in:

```java
@Endpoint
public class MessageEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( MessageEndpoint.class );

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://ws.transit.ls.com";


    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "Multiply")
    @ResponsePayload
    public MultiplyResponse getMultiplyResponse(@RequestPayload Multiply messageRequest) throws Exception {

        String fileName = messageRequest.getFileName1();

...
```

You also must to use the xsd with able to work **adjoining system** (must not change nothig into the xsd)

If you are creating new Web-service Soap and from first to create an application that another clients will adhering your an xsd.

But in the my case I must adhere rules the **enjoining system**.